# how to make tclsh backspace key working properly

Tags: tclsh

I am using tclsh on a unix system. The TCL shell (8.6)
is installed properly and works as expected.
However, when I use tclsh interactively,
the backspace key does not work.

When I hit the keyboard  I get: "^?" instead.

That is rather annoying because I have to retype the whole line.
Is there any way to make  working normally?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed a similar problem in Vim with this shell command.

```
stty erase '^?'
```

Put this into the config file that is read by your shell in interactive mode.